# Add struct to Combobox and display struct member as selected item

Tags: wpf, combobox, struct

I got a simple struct

```
private struct _config
{
    public string name;
    public int id;
}
```

I want to add it to a combobox but show name as the displayed name in the combobox. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly suggest reading the links HB posted, however here's the code you're looking to work towards:

Change your ComboBox items to have get/set accessor methods:

```
private struct Config
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then your ComboBox XAML should look like this

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Answer (score 2):

[Data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and [templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx), you will need properties instead of fields though.

(As you just want text you can ditch the templating and use [`DisplayMemberPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx) as well)

Comment: You should change that to "will" instead of "may".

Comment: @mydogisbox: I should indeed, was wondering about whether `DisplayMemberPath` works with fields though..

Comment: @mydogisbox: Apparently, as it uses binding as well it does not.

Comment: Huh, I always thought it did.  Guess I learned something as well.

Comment: @mydogisbox I learned the hard way that `DisplayMemberPath` is simply a shortcut way of making an `ItemTemplate` containing a `TextBlock` bound to whatever value is in `DisplayMemberPath`

Answer (score 1):

The `ComboBox`, in the absense of anything else, just uses the `ToString()` method of whatever stuff you put into its `.Items` to display them. So a quick and dirty way to do this would just be override the `ToString()` method of the struct to return the name, i.e.,

```
private struct _config
{
    public string name;
    public int id;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```